# snippet not recognized -- yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet

my question is pretty basic but I don't know how to create yasnippets properly. I have created some snippets for `Java` or `html` with `yas-new-snippets`, installed them under emacs.d/snippets/org-mode, but they only work when I invoke them from `org-mode` , not from Java-mode (or JDEE) or html-mode, which is not very useful...

Here is my config file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
         "~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20160801.1142")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "~/.emacs.d/snippets")
```

The variable `yas-snippet-dirs` yields:
("~/.emacs.d/snippets" "/Users/me/.emacs.d/snippets" yas-installed-snippets-dir) so I tried to put directly under .emacs.d/snippets/ but they are not recognized.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the right table ?  `yas-new-snippet` creates the snippets for org mode if you use it in an org-mode buffer, except you changed the table manually. In other words, each major-mode got its own snippets and snippet directory.